# In JavaScript does /** have any special meaning?

Tags: javascript, comments

I know I can add comments like so:

```
//This is a comment,
/*so is this*/
```

But when I do this

```
/**comment?*/
```

It has a different color in my text editor (notepad++) and I was wondering whether it has any special meaning, or if it is just a random feature of notepad++.

Here is what it looks like in the text editor:

[image: Image of the query. Shows how the special comment is a darker shade than normal.]

Comment: It depends on editor implementation. In real life there is n special meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in JavaScript itself, but some editors will treat it like a JSDoc (https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc) comment to help with autocomplete, etc.

You can also run your code through something like JSDoc to automatically generate HTML documentation for your codebase.

Comment: Is there any other information you can provide on a jsDoc?

Comment: I know you can get plugins for certain editors (NetBeans and Sublime, for example) where you can do /**[Enter] above a method/function, and it will give you a template with parameters, etc.

Basically though, they end up something like this (off the top of my head):

/**
 * [at]description Description of my method
 * [at]param       {Object} some object you need to pass
 */

Best to look in the github repo I linked to though. There is far more info there than I can remember.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't have any special meaning. It's more common to use that syntax when documenting code via. comments.

Answer (score 3):

The Java language supports three kinds of comments:

/* text */The compiler ignores everything from /* to */.

/** documentation */
This indicates a documentation comment (doc comment, for short). The compiler ignores this kind of comment, just like it ignores comments that use /* and */. The JDK javadoc tool uses doc comments when preparing automatically generated documentation. For more information on javadoc, see the Java tool documentation.

// text
The compiler ignores everything from // to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Probably notepad++ identifies it with two different colors just to diversify the type of comment. for a programmer a comment may be more or less important than another :)

might seem like a silly feature, but it is not